# How to land "Late" tricks?

Tags: technique, skateboarding

I have recently been trying to land "Late Shuvs" and "Late Kickflips". Now to achieve these tricks you need to have ollied befor you initiate the trick. I get the Ollie fine for the Shuv and kicking the board to make the 180 rotation is fine but the part I'm struggle with is landing on top of it, it always spins away or behind me. what am I doing wrong?

Also for the late flip how do I even flip the board when its in the air? when I kick it, it instantly point s towards the floor. (and causes really bad injuries I must add...)

Comment: Adding this as a comment, since I'm far less experienced than you are, but from personal research and experience trying to land basic shuvs the cause and effect of the board going behind or out to the side should be the same; i.e. your centre of mass is not directly over the board and/or your front foot isn't in the correct pivot position to keep the rotation under control.

I've only watched videos of late flips, way out of my skill set right now, but if you are pushing the board directly down it sounds like you are applying too much force centrally on the board. Try more out and down?

Comment: @Scoll Yeah thanks for that, I had the same thought process as you on this one. it seems to be just down to process of elimination with foot stances and finding the right one... this is on-going so I will express my findings when I get back on the board. thanks again! :)